# What jig or template can I use to be able to drill in place through horizontal fence boards to be dead on holes in a steel post?

Tags: drill

Imagine that I need to drill through boards that will be set horizontally and they will need to be attached to a post like below. For simplicity I will say that the boards will sit on top of each other and will be installed from bottom to top. This is a horizontal fence

The steep post has .20" diameter holes spaced 1" from each other
As in the picture on the other side there is a piece of 2x2 that is already screwed to the post. The post will be sandwiched between the boards and the backer 2x2  (see the detailed picture, zoom in at the bottom of this post)

I think I need a jig that will consist of a piece of wood with three short #10 machine screws that will lock the jig into position, vertically and then predrilled holes in the jig, holes that I will use as guide for drilling new ones
Yesterday I tried a similar approach but with screws ...their tip is very sharp and the jig (made slightly different) had errors and I ruined a couple of boards

[Here](https://www.masterhalco.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/PM-Install-TearPad-011480-English.pdf) are the specs and the instructions for this type of post

Any other I idea ?

Update: here is the fence I am trying to build
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think one would need a jig. Just scribe or snap two lines on the board equal to the distance between the outside edges of the metal posts. Screw or nail  comfortably outside those lines. Please report back with pictures when you have finished. This looks like it will be a cleverly designed and nicely done  fence.

Comment: Measure the reveal on the left vertical. Place the board where you want it and put one screw or nail top left. Check for plumb then nail or screw by eye down on left. Measure position of metal post at top right and screw or nail on right between that and the edge of the board. Predrill the board if you're worried about splitting.

Comment: i think that you are supposed to attach the horizontals before you attach the verticals ....... it is unclear what you are actually doing

Comment: I am doing a horizontal fence. See the update

Comment: @JimStewart I don't think you got the idea, i need to put holes through the board that will match the holes on the post. I do not want to screw the boards into the 1/2" left uncovered by the post

Comment: There is no benefit to doing what you want to do, but if you insist then select the holes you want to go into and drill small holes in each and put small brads or finish nails into the center of each of the holes. Hold the board up to the nails and tap with a hammer to mark each spot. Drill through the back and you should have holes in the right spot. Pull the finish nails and line up the holes in the board with those in the under board. But I repeat there would not appear to be any point to this.

Comment: Could you take an extra post, align the tops of the posts and use the holes in the  extra post as a drill guide?

Comment: it is heavy like hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this jig actually works
Take a piece of wood like the one below
Align it vertically on the flagne
Use the post as drilling template to create the wholes as seen below
Put three #10 machine screws long enough to reach the post when the board you need to attach to the post is sandwiched between your jig and the post.Secure the screws with nuts.
Now to use the jig align the holes on the post and the holes on the jig by inserting the three ends of the screws in holes on the post while the area of the jig free of screws lays over the board you need to drill in. Now your jig indicates where you can drill in the board to match the post holes. Predrill and then install the screws

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pegboard comes predrilled in a 1" grid, just like the holes on your posts. Cut a strip out of a sheet, line it up with the holes on the post, and attach a reference block to the top. Et voila, instant story board.

Comment: I will have to uncheck this as answer, the peg boar has way too large wholes compared with the holes that the post has. I will soon post what I  end up using...I am testing my solution this afternoon...

Answer (score 0):

As i see it in this photo it is unnecessary to use each of the holes in the metal post.

Just secure the vertical post filler board (green in the photo ) to the metal post first , insure that it is wider by enough to fasten to. You can then screw your fence board to the wood of this vertical board, Pre-drill pilot holes to prevent splitting. No need to take time making a jig.

Comment: Please review your answer after looking at the update that I added to my OP

Comment: @MiniMe  I have reviewed the update and i still would do as i stated in my answer. All you need to do is attach boards to the flanges of the metal posts and you have a wood surface to attach your horizontal  fence boards to. This effectively turns your metal post into a wood post as if you had used a 4x4 post.

Comment: and it increases the gap between boards (which are alternating on each face) making the fence looking like a closet, ugly spaces there

Comment: @ MiniMe  Knock your self out, if you want to make a jig then make jig.

Comment: I don't want to , but it seems that I have to

Comment: i disagree, i and do not see why you think you have to. get  a spare metal post and take  a scrap of wood long enough and put a small piece of scrap at the top to be a reference guide stop . Place this board onto the metal post with the stop siting on the top, align it and clamp it in place so it does not move. Mark the holes through the metal post onto the board with a pencil, drill these marks with the appropriate pilot bit.  voila, template.

Comment: I did that initially as you said but I used a drill and the bit for the screws..the bit was too small and  it resulted in alignment errors. I am now building a tighter one using #10 machine screws, harder wood, and a drill bit that is very close to the size of the holes in the post. I tested last night and it seemed to work on a test board. I will use it today when I get back from work and confirm if this is a practical solution